# Export SP List Column w/ Version History to Excel

Tags: list

I'm having trouble thinking up a good way of being able to export specifically a column or columns and including the version history of items in a list to excel. Here's an example of what  I want. Let's say I have a column for "money", and I have 10 items in the list. I want to be able to export a file to excel that will include each instance of the version history, including what the previous "money" value was, what it is currently, who modified it, and when it was modified. I do not have access to being able to install plugins, so everything I can do has to be done either with views, workflows, or csom.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot do that with CSOM because **SPListItemVersion** does not exist.

If you could use server side c#, this is a [solution](http://surpoint.blogspot.com.ar/2014/09/listar-en-sharepoint-items-con.html) I implemented.

Another option is use  [SPServices CodePlex JS](http://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation). I did not tested, but you can see in this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/d2c641ef-b0cf-4ce7-8df3-85bbecdc5dd9/equivalent-of-splistitemversion-in-csom?forum=appsforsharepoint) that it is a possible solution in the client side.

Hope it will be helfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Microsoft Flow you can send an Http Request against your List to get your needed items. In the response of that Request you find a Field called "Odata_UIVersionString".

This Field contains the Version number of the item.

You won't be able to get the field automaticle suggested. Instead you need to know about it and get the value by adding it as Expression, e.g. in a variable-action[image]

I hope this helps you out. Please let me know :-)